# How to expand a column that is inside a container, so that an image could expand from the column middlepoint to the right side of the page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Within bootstrap container I would like to extend my image to the side but keep the rest the same. To make it more explainable; this is what I have at the moment:[image: Bootstrap container with sidesbar]. On the right side of the image there's a gap. I would like to extend the image over that gap (green line) but keep the middle of the column on the same page (red line). Explained in the image: [image: What I would like]

But I am having trouble to achieve this with the container. I know I could use container-fluid, but to keep my layout consistant I would like to use container for this matter. Because when I use container-fluid the margins are off and it's not as cleaned lined up as I would like to.

Thanks in advance, I can't seem to figure this out without messing up the layout.

**EDIT 1**

My bad fogot to add the code; herby my code:

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <section class="col pt-5">
                    <div>
                        <h1>Welkom bij</h1>
                        <h1>XE-Designs</h1>
                        <p>Easy furniture rental with white glove delivery & assembly. Currently in NYC, SF, LA, Baltimore, Richmond, and the DC Area!</p>
                    </div>
                </section>
                    
                <section class="col">
                    <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="~/images/barn-images-t5YUoHW6zRo-unsplash.jpg"  />
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this](http://www.simon-li.com/design-and-code/an-elegant-way-to-break-the-bootstrap-container/) explanation I achieved what I wanted. It's about break the bootstrap container. By reversing the used calculation I knew what attributes to use. I've drawn it out for myself and came to the correct calculation to use. This is the html I used:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <section class="col-md-6 d-flex align-items-center">
                    <div>
                        <h1>Welkom bij</h1>
                        <h1>XE-Designs</h1>
                        <p>Easy furniture rental with white glove delivery & assembly. Currently in NYC, SF, LA, Baltimore, Richmond, and the DC Area!</p>
                    </div>
                </section>

                <section class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="css_break_out">
                        <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="~/images/barn-images-t5YUoHW6zRo-unsplash.jpg" />
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
```

For my css I used the following:

```
.css_break_out {
        width: calc((100% + (100vw - 100%) / 2) + 15px);
        position: relative;
        left: calc(-1 * (100vw - 100%) / 2);
    }

    @@media (min-width: 576px) {
        .css_break_out {
            width: calc((100% + (100vw - 100% - 15px)));
            position: relative;
            left: calc(-1 * (100vw - 100% - 15px) / 2);
        }
    }

    @@media (min-width: 768px) {
        .css_break_out {
            width: calc((100% + (100vw - 200%) / 2) - 15px);
            position: relative;
            left: 0;
        }
    }
```

If someone has any improvement within these css/ html, let me know, I am willing to edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

On your div with `row` class name you can either use `d-flex`

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container bg-secondary">
  <div class="row p-2">
    <section class="col pt-5 border border-white">
      <div>
        <h1>Welkom bij</h1>
        <h1>XE-Designs</h1>
        <p>
          Easy furniture rental with white glove delivery & assembly. Currently in NYC, SF, LA, Baltimore, Richmond, and the DC Area!
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- d-flex and align-items-center is to display flexbox and vertically align child items to center-->
    <section class="col d-flex align-items-center border border-white">
      <!--If you're using latest version of bootstrap use ms-auto and d-block, if not, use ml-auto.
      You have to make your image smaller than your container, if w-100 then it takes width: 100%-->
      <img class="img-fluid w-75 bg-dark d-block h-75 ms-auto" src="~/images/barn-images-t5YUoHW6zRo-unsplash.jpg"/>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just tried it but it does not seem to work; it wont extend the image to the page border. It does not 'breakout' of it's parent container

Comment: Ok, I understand, since your image is taking full width this won't be possible, if you want to reflect this you would need to modify your container right padding, but even with this image would take 100% of width and cols will grow taking al the available space, so i would recommend you to do as in my edit

Comment: Sad anough same result again :/

Comment: Already edited, in my previous comment i explain why this happens and how you can solve it.

Comment: Your answer does give some insights, but there is still an limitation of the parent container. So as example I there is the whole page, within that page there's the container and the container contains a grid so there's an even seperation. Within the second grid I would like to extend it to the page bord (so outside the container parameters). I can't see to figure this part out